# Category name for "Other fun stuff" vs "Other serious stuff"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, internet

On my website, I currently have seven categories.

- Games
- Art
- Music
- Video
- Text
- Other
- Misc

"Other" is for other things that are fun, like games, art, music, video, and text. For example, a fireworks simulator would fit in the "other" category because it's not really a game, just a fun thing.

"Miscellaneous" is for non-fun things, like my contact page or my copyright license.

However, a visitor to my website won't know this, and would probably be confused as to what the difference is.

What could I rename these categories to, so that a visitor would realize that one is for entertainment, and the other is not?

Comment: (by the way, this is my first question on ELU, so please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong!)

Comment: Now, *this* is fun!

Comment: However, the trend is to be more direct and up-front in menu names. Instead of *Other*, "Games & more" would be more like it. Also, Contact Page & Copyright License are, as you rightly noted, "serious", not "miscellaneous," things. Try not to combine them. "Contact Us" always deserves a page of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Instead of “Other” you could write “Fun Stuff” or “Other Fun Stuff”.  Also consider titles like  “Catchall” or  “Curios” or “Curiosities” or “Useful & Fun”.

(2) On many websites, a page with contact or copyright information or miscellaneous housekeeping notes would be labeled “Contact Us”,  “About Us”, or  “Site Map”.  A “Site Map” should provide an organized directory of pages on a website, but sometimes includes other data too. 
Actually, most “Site Map” pages I've looked at were of no help in navigating the site, so having a page called “Site Map” is not necessarily a plus.

Comment: Thanks, all of the items in point (1) are great! Point (2) though won't work because "Contact Us" or "About Us" would only fit the "contact" page, not the copyright license or some of that other miscellaneous stuff. I could use a term from (1) and use "Misc" or "Other" for (2), so this might work! +1

Answer (score 1):

I like *curios* for the fun stuff. Another creative way to categorize your pages is to use verbs instead. For your existing pages you might use

- Play
- Observe
- Listen
- Watch
- Read
- Enjoy
- Learn

Or something...